# How discover if PHP from Dreamweaver

Tags: php, file, validation, call, dreamweaver

How can I discover if a called to PHP is made from Dreamweaver to check a file s correct?

Like one of my is called `Utilities.php`. Dreamweaver makes `Utilities_3ooftqaeu3.php` and sends it to PHP.

My problem is in my code I execute

```
header( "location: ".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

and because `Utilities_3ooftqaeu3.php` doesn't exist Dreamweaver reports an validation error.

Is there a way out of this? The easiest would be if I could recognise that Dreamweaver has made the call to PHP and then not execute `header()` command

Comment: I haven't used Dreamweaver in over 10 years... but this problem sounds vaguely familiar.  Can you describe in more detail?  When does Dreamweaver generate these file names?  That's in some preview mode, right?

Comment: Are you using a pirated version of Dreamweaver ?

Comment: No I am NOT using a pirated version but I have bought my version of CS6.

When a file has a syntax error DW displays on the top a yellow banner and highlights the line in question

Comment: @Peter you can use https://www.sublimetext.com/2 for now, and Open a support ticket with Dreamweaver https://helpx.adobe.com/contact.html